# Custom Tableview Slide Action

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

How can I create a custom slide action on a tableView Cell like the one shown below (video here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFsJ4.jpg). I am specifically unsure about the rounded view that they have created to contain the slide action. Any information/expertise would be extremely helpful! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: have you tried editActionsForRowAtIndexPath ? You can easily customize the image

Comment: @KeshuRai My main concern is the actual 'container' that the cell is put in on slide.  How are they creating the rounded edges and trailing and leading constraint that only shows on slide...

Answer (score 0):

Change as per your requirement:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Share") { action, index in
        print("share button tapped")
    }
    share.backgroundColor = .blue

    return [share]
}
```

For cell with rounded corners use this:

```
tableView.containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
tableView.containerView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: My main concern is the actual 'container' that the cell is put in on slide. How are they creating the rounded edges and trailing and leading constraint that only shows on slide...

Comment: @mink23 check revised answer

Comment: Just set cornerRadius of the containerView of the tableView

Comment: What containerView? Where is this referred to in the Apple Docs?